# How to create subset of data based on data type when using NumPy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Objective:** to generate a subset of the original data based on dtype

How can I use NumPy to create a subset of columns based on dtypes. More specifically, using the below example, how can I create a NumPy object that only contains the float values `('<f8')` in a new dataset.

```
Example
--------
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [0.5, 0.75]},
...                   index=['a', 'b'])
>>> df
   A     B
a  1  0.50
b  2  0.75
>>> df.to_records()
rec.array([('a', 1, 0.5 ), ('b', 2, 0.75)],
          dtype=[('index', 'O'), ('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<f8')])
```

**EDIT:**
I was hoping I could make use of something like the following:

```
np.where(my_np_array.dtype==[('int64')])
```

which would give me all columns with `'<i8'` and exclude all the `'<f8'` columns in the example case above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to do this kind of selection before, but let's look at the compound dtype.

```
In [21]: M                                                                      
Out[21]: 
rec.array([('a', 1, 0.5 ), ('b', 2, 0.75)],
          dtype=[('index', 'O'), ('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<f8')])
In [22]: M.dtype.fields                                                         
Out[22]: 
mappingproxy({'index': (dtype('O'), 0),
              'A': (dtype('int64'), 8),
              'B': (dtype('float64'), 16)})
```

I can get a list of field names with this comprehension:

```
In [23]: [f[0] for f in M.dtype.fields.items() if f[1][0]==np.int64]            
Out[23]: ['A']
In [24]: M[_]                                                                   
Out[24]: 
rec.array([(1,), (2,)],
          dtype={'names':['A'], 'formats':['<i8'], 'offsets':[8], 'itemsize':24})
```